# How to get List<ColumnType> in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have **Establishment table** as shown below,

```
EstabId    Name                      CheckinDate
114883  Marconfort Griego Hotel   2011-09-28 00:00:00.000
114910  Royal Costa Hotel         2011-10-18 00:00:00.000
114912  Roc Flamingo Hotel        2011-11-22 00:00:00.000
114912  Roc Flamingo Hotel        2011-11-29 00:00:00.000
114912  Roc Flamingo Hotel        2011-12-06 00:00:00.000
114912  Roc Flamingo Hotel        2011-12-13 00:00:00.000
114912  Roc Flamingo Hotel        2011-12-20 00:00:00.000
114894  Gran Hotel Blue Sea       2012-01-17 00:00:00.000
114894  Gran Hotel Blue Sea       2012-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Suppose, If I want to **structure my query result** like,

```
Response  : {
  [
   EstabId: 114912,
   Name: 'Roc Flamingo Hotel',
   CheckinDates : [2011-11-22 00:00:00.000, 2011-11-29 00:00:00.000, 2011-12-06 00:00:00.000, 2011-12-13 00:00:00.000, 2011-12-20 00:00:00.000]
   ,... ]
}
```

Is, there any recommended way to achieve this structure from `SQL Stored Procedure` or `C# + SQL combination`?

PS: I heard, SQL SERVER will not support List

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need only list of checkinDate for a given id and name?

Comment: no, I want `List<Establishment>`, Inside Establishment, `List<CheckindDate>`

Comment: Yes, there is. It is called programming. WAY too broad because you basically tell us you have no clue how to program - this is quite basic.

Comment: Thanks @tom, I could solve it using some for loop, But, I wanted to know, If there is some better way to do so.

Comment: LINQ. The for loop can be a select projection. But that again is very dependent what you actually DO with the output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. But you should also read [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) article for specific needs.

This query will return the result with comma separated check in dates which you can store in a collection of Establishment class.

```
SELECT es1.EstabId , es2.Name , 
( 
SELECT @CheckInDateList   = COALESCE(@CheckInDateList +',' ,'') + CheckinDate
                     FROM Establishment es2 
WHERE 
es2.EstabId = es1.EstabId
AND
es2.Name = es1.Name
) as CheckinDates

FROM Establishment es1
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a class like this

```
public class Checkins
{
    public int EstabId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> CheckInDates { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an Checkin instance and fill the data from you Databse. Finally serialize this instance to get the expected result.